# REQUEST_URI of a php document is "favicon.ico" or a stylesheet's filename

Tags: php, request, uri, favicon

I log traffic coming in to my site. I get a user's landing page by looking at the REQUEST_URI of the first page they come to. The site is all php so every page includes a file that has, among some other things:

```
$_SESSION['landing']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I also log traffic going out.  I've noticed two kinds of entries for $_SESSION['landing'] though that don't quite make sense. I'll see either: "favicon.ico" or "ie8.css"

Favicon is just a favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.SITE.com/images/favicon.ico" />
```

ie8.css is a stylesheet that fixes a couple of things so they'll look right in IE8. I include it like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Why would these show up as the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for a php document?

Comment: Do you have a missing `favicon.ico` which lands on a PHP 404 page and/or is your CSS files preprocessed with (ran through) PHP?

Comment: no to both of those.  I guess what they have in common is the link rel tag <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.SITE.com/images/favicon.ico" />

Comment: oh wait, I found a case where a link to the css is written wrong so it would give a 404! Ahh there must be a similar case for the favicon too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are 3 reason i know that can cause such error ...

1. Error  URL redirection .... when trying to implement clean URL ....
2. `AddType x-httpd-php .css .ico .xyz
3. Someone is messing with your server ....

I hope this helps

Comment: It was 404's like Alex suggested, but you were right they were caused by URL redirection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This for steering me in the right direction. I was using a rewrite rule to simulate a "county" directory e.g. :

```
/county/Sonoma?1, /county/Sonoma?2, etc.
```

to distinguish counties from cities which look like /Santa Rosa. This is the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/\.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^county/(.+)$ /county.php?county=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but my link to favicon.ico was relative, not absolute, i.e. `favicon.icon` instead of `/favicon.ico`. So apache was looking for `/county/favicon.ico` instead of `/favicon.ico`. And the RewriteRule was sending it to county.php.

The upshot was that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` was `/favicon.ico.`

I prepended the slash and it worked. And for good measure I added another rule:

```
RewriteRule ^county/(.+/.+)$ /$1 [L]
```

just in case.